# Find Max Element in a list by comparing value of each element in Tcl

Tags: list, foreach, tcl, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a list and find the max value by comparing each element of the list with every other element using simple command and not inbuilt commands.

For Example:

```
    set a 9 ; set b 2 ; set c 11; set d 1
    
    set list [list $a $b $c $d]
    
    set max [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$list]

    11
```

This returns answer as 11 correctly

but when I do this:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list]}  {incr i} {
    set tmp1 [lindex $list  $i]
    set tmp2  [lindex $list  $i+1]
    if {$tmp1 > $tmp2 } {
        set results $tmp1
    } else {
    set results $tmp2
    }
}
```

I get "puts $results" as 1

I try to print all variable values and see tmp1 becomes 1 in the end.

```
tmp1: 9 i: 0 tmp2: 2
tmp1: 2 i: 1 tmp2: 11
tmp1: 11 i: 2 tmp2: 1
tmp1: 1 i: 3 tmp2:
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your last time through the loop tries to get an index that doesn't exist in the list.

Comment: You also never compare to the current value of `results` like you should.

Comment: @Shawn Could you help correct the code ? and post a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a learning exercise for you, I'm not going to give a complete answer.

You sort integers using `lsort -integer`. Then you can use `lindex` to pick a value from that; you might find either the index `0` (the first value) or `end` (the last value) rather helpful.

Alternatively, the standard way to loop over a list of values is with `foreach`, and this leads to this natural way to find the maximum:

```
foreach val $values {
    if {$val > $max} {
        set max $val
    }
}
```

However, you need to think what the initial value of `max` should be; what does it mean to be less than everything else? What is the maximum of an empty list?

---

The method in the question is totally how I'd find the maximum, provided I needed just that. If I need anything more complex, I'd probably do a linear scan unless I have information about whether the list is sorted.

Comment: % set max ""
% set values [list $a $b $c]
90 80 500
% foreach val $values {
    if {$val > $max} {
        set max $val
    }
}
% puts $max
500

Comment: I would initialize max with `set max [lindex $values 0]` unless the list is empty. Then you have a valid value for the first `$val > $max`